# Reading the contents of a file into a dynamically allocated array in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, dynamic-arrays, dynamically-generated

So I'm attempting to compare the individual characters from each file inputted which are then read to two char pointers allocated into memory with the size of the two input files. Whenever the entire program is executed, the second file that's supposed to contain all the differences in the second file inputted from the first file inputted is blank. I'm not sure if it's a problem reading the contents of each file into the arrays or what. Can someone please help me out?

Main method:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  int file1 = -1, file2 = -1, fileDif1 = -1, fileDif2 = -1;
  file1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  file2 = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
  fileDif1 = open("differencesFoundInFile1.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);
  fileDif2 = open("differencesFoundInFile2.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0700);
  handleExceptions(argc, argv[1], argv[2], file1, file2, fileDif1, fileDif2);

  step1(file1, file2, fileDif1);
  step2(argv[1], argv[2], file1, file2, fileDif2);

  close(file1);
  close(file2);
  close(fileDif1);
  close(fileDif2);
  return 0;
}
```

step 2, where the error is

```
void step2(const char * argv1, const char * argv2, int file1, int file2, int fileDif2) {
    struct timeval begin, end;
    gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);

    struct stat fileStat1;
    struct stat fileStat2;
    stat(argv1, &fileStat1);
    stat(argv2, &fileStat2);
    int size1 = fileStat1.st_size;
    int size2 = fileStat2.st_size;

    char * fileArray1 = malloc(size1), * fileArray2 = malloc(size2); //create array
    read(file1, fileArray1, size1); //store bytes in array
    read(file2, fileArray2, size2); //store bytes in array

    //check for differences and write to file if found
    for(int i = 0; i < size2; i++){
        if(fileArray1[i] != fileArray2[i]){
            write(fileDif2, &fileArray2[i], 1);
        }
    }

    free(fileArray1);
    free(fileArray2);

    //calculate time of completion
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    printf("Step 2 took %f milliseconds\n",
           (((double)end.tv_usec / 1000) - ((double)begin.tv_usec / 1000)));
}
```

Libraries:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

`step1()`:

```
    void step1 (int file1, int file2, int fileDif1) {
    struct timeval begin, end;
    gettimeofday(&begin, NULL); //begin timer
    int bufferSize = 2;
    char * buffer1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferSize), * buffer2 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferSize);
    buffer1[bufferSize - 1] = '\0';
    buffer2[bufferSize - 1] = '\0';

    int bytesRead = read(file1, buffer1, bufferSize - 1);
    read(file2, buffer2, bufferSize - 1);
    while(bytesRead > 0){
        buffer1[bytesRead] = '\0';
        buffer2[bytesRead] = '\0';
        if(*buffer1!=*buffer2) {
            write(fileDif1, buffer1, bytesRead);
        }
        bytesRead = read(file1, buffer1, bufferSize - 1);
        read(file2, buffer2, bufferSize - 1);
    }

    free(buffer1);
    free(buffer2);

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    printf("Step 1 took %f milliseconds\n",
           (((double)end.tv_usec / 1000) - ((double)begin.tv_usec / 1000)));
}
```

So what I was attempting to do was to read in the contents of text files within the same directory as the c file itself. Then, in step2, the two file's contents are supposed to be stored at the location of two char pointers of the same size of the files. The contents now stored in the two pointers are supposed to be iterated through and compared to see whether or not the second file has any differences from the first file. These differences are then supposed to be written in a new file. The new file does generate but it does not contain any of the different characters. I don't know which part of the method is the issue and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using unbuffered I/O?  Normally one would use `fread`.  In any case, you need to check the return value from `read`.  Otherwise you have no way of knowing how many bytes were actually read.  You also forgot to check the return value from `open`, so if there was an error, your program will crash and burn rather than handling it reasonably.  Similarly for `write` (again, why not use `fwrite`?)

Comment: It's a project and I'm forced to use `open` and `read` instead of `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: The mysterious `handleExceptions()` would, it seems, be validating certain things AFTER some of those certain things have already been presumed to be valid. Don't hide logic in some mysterious "swiss army knife" function... Code should make sense to the reader...

Comment: @Fe2O3 whaddya mean? `step1()` is inconsequential to the error here and works perfectly fine. It's entirely functional.

Comment: WILD GUESS: Does the mysterious `step1()` read to the end of `file1` and `file2`? Where do you think the read pointer is at after this? Unseen code cannot be debugged.

Comment: What do I mean? I mean what I wrote: "code should make sense to the reader." You are the one asking for help. What's the point of asking if you don't want to supply necessary (perhaps "relevant") information?

Comment: As suspected: `step1()` reads to the end of the files, then `step2()` is called without some kind of `seek()` back to the beginning of the files... See how easy it can be?

Comment: @Fe2O3 I added the method per request

Comment: Suggestion: Since `step2()` allocates (and uses) two full sized buffers (one for each file), it would be simpler to do this once (`step0()` ?), then perform whatever measured comparisons you want against those two buffers instead of attempting to read from the file(s) twice. Then, `step4()` frees those two buffers...

Comment: @Zodiac Whenever you use these functions to open. read, or write a file, you always need to check the return value.  It not only indicates if an error occurred, but in the case of `read` and `write`, it tells you how many bytes were transferred.  This may be less than what you requested.  Remember, it's unbuffered.  It's not an error if the number of transferred bytes is less.  In that case, you need to continue reading/writing until all data has been transferred.  You would do well to read the man pages for these functions, rather than blindly assuming you understand them.

Answer (score 0):

###### Possible bugs

The problem could be, that [close()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) does not flush buffered content. The doc says: `If you need to be sure that the data is physically stored on the underlying disk, use fsync(2)` [fsync()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html). Alternative would be to use `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`, [that handle that for you](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html).

Also before calling `step2()`, you should call `fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_SET);`. Same for a `file2`. Otherwise, the file descriptors point to the end of the files.

---

###### Note about bufferSize = 2:

If you increase `bufferSize` in `step1` to be more than `2`, the condition for checking file equality `if(*buffer1!=*buffer2)` would stop working. It checks just the first character. You could use [strncmp()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) for comparing longer buffers.

---

###### Note about return values

Also keep in mind that the functions `open()`, `read()`, `write()` and `close()` are returning something for a reason. Those functions can easily fail and values should be checked for sure. Your code does not need to handle those errors, but at least print a message to stderr, so you know if your code fails.

Comment: `fseek()` wouldn't work because `file1` and `file2` are file descriptors and not directly linked to the files themselves. I tried `lseek()` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It depends on what you need, but `O_SYNC` (and `O_DSYNC` and `O_RSYNC`) allow a lot of control, but you don't usually need to worry about that.  When you close the file descriptor, the data written with `write()` will be written to disk by the kernel, barring catastrophes, and can be read by other processes.  If there is client-side buffering, then those buffers will not be flushed when you close the file descriptor.  Using standard I/O and `fopen()`, `fclose()` and the various I/O functions has client-side buffering, but `fclose()` ensures that buffered data is handled properly.